# low memory allocated for compiled swf?

Tags: flash, away3d

I just encountered a strange problem, after seeing some away3d examples running with decent fps even with a lot of polygons I tried to reply that success but ended up having a terrible low fps even with the simplest of my models, what I did observed was that my test used a lot less memory to run, about 24 mb while the one I saw were about 300 mb, so I figured out that it is due to this fact that I failed. My question is how can I allow more memory to the running swf, or what did I did wrong to end in this situation.

I will appreciate all your answers.

With respect,
khael